# JFreeChart: Panning without the CTRL modifier

Tags: java, jfreechart

I will be using JFreeChart to display charts on a tablet with windows 8. The problem is, there is no <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key on the tablet in order to pan around the chart. Is there a way to override the method so that instead of selecting the area to zoom when you click, you pan instead?

I have tried using AutoHotKey scripts to hold the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key down as a solution but unfortunately that doesn't work

Comment: Have you already found a solution for that problem? I am struggling with the same problem at the moment and can't find any solution :(

Comment: FYI, [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193099/pan-chart-using-mouse-jfreechart/31230431#31230431)

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31193099/230513).