# Pan chart using mouse - Jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Can we implement the pan functionality as a mouse drag event in JfreeChart? Right now I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and drag my mouse to pan a chart. I want to implement the pan functionality just by dragging the mouse. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

It is apparently impossible to change the modifier key with the current JFreeChart API, as discussed [here](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116844) (but it is in the pipeline).

However, everything is there to pan a chart programmatically, so you could try the following:

- Add a `MouseMotionListener` to your `ChartPanel` to track `mouseDragged()` events.
- From these events, compute the requested movement of the chart.
- Call directly `XYPlot.panDomainAxes()` and `XYPlot.panRangeAxis()` (API [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#panDomainAxes-double-org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotRenderingInfo-java.awt.geom.Point2D-)).

Take inspiration from `ChartPanel` [source code](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html):

```
/** 
 * Temporary storage for the width and height of the chart 
 * drawing area during panning.
 */
private double panW, panH;

/** The last mouse position during panning. */
private Point panLast;

/**
 * The mask for mouse events to trigger panning.
 *
 * @since 1.0.13
 */
private int panMask = InputEvent.CTRL_MASK;

...

/**
 * Handles a 'mouse pressed' event.
 * <P>
 * This event is the popup trigger on Unix/Linux.  For Windows, the popup
 * trigger is the 'mouse released' event.
 *
 * @param e  The mouse event.
 */
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if (this.chart == null) {
        return;
    }
    Plot plot = this.chart.getPlot();
    int mods = e.getModifiers();
    if ((mods & this.panMask) == this.panMask) {
        // can we pan this plot?
        if (plot instanceof Pannable) {
            Pannable pannable = (Pannable) plot;
            if (pannable.isDomainPannable() || pannable.isRangePannable()) {
                Rectangle2D screenDataArea = getScreenDataArea(e.getX(),
                        e.getY());
                if (screenDataArea != null && screenDataArea.contains(
                        e.getPoint())) {
                    this.panW = screenDataArea.getWidth();
                    this.panH = screenDataArea.getHeight();
                    this.panLast = e.getPoint();
                    setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(
                            Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
                }
            }
            // the actual panning occurs later in the mouseDragged() 
            // method
        }
    }
    else if (this.zoomRectangle == null) {
        ...
    }
}

...

/**
 * Handles a 'mouse dragged' event.
 *
 * @param e  the mouse event.
 */
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    // if the popup menu has already been triggered, then ignore dragging...
    if (this.popup != null && this.popup.isShowing()) {
        return;
    }

    // handle panning if we have a start point
    if (this.panLast != null) {
        double dx = e.getX() - this.panLast.getX();
        double dy = e.getY() - this.panLast.getY();
        if (dx == 0.0 && dy == 0.0) {
            return;
        }
        double wPercent = -dx / this.panW;
        double hPercent = dy / this.panH;
        boolean old = this.chart.getPlot().isNotify();
        this.chart.getPlot().setNotify(false);
        Pannable p = (Pannable) this.chart.getPlot();
        if (p.getOrientation() == PlotOrientation.VERTICAL) {
            p.panDomainAxes(wPercent, this.info.getPlotInfo(),
                    this.panLast);
            p.panRangeAxes(hPercent, this.info.getPlotInfo(),
                    this.panLast);
        }
        else {
            p.panDomainAxes(hPercent, this.info.getPlotInfo(),
                    this.panLast);
            p.panRangeAxes(wPercent, this.info.getPlotInfo(),
                    this.panLast);
        }
        this.panLast = e.getPoint();
        this.chart.getPlot().setNotify(old);
        return;
    }

    ...

}

...

/**
 * Handles a 'mouse released' event.  On Windows, we need to check if this
 * is a popup trigger, but only if we haven't already been tracking a zoom
 * rectangle.
 *
 * @param e  information about the event.
 */
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    // if we've been panning, we need to reset now that the mouse is 
    // released...
    if (this.panLast != null) {
        this.panLast = null;
        setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
    }

    ...

}
```

**EDIT:** Noticing that the only problem with the current API is that `panMask` is private, why don't you try to hack the field with reflection:

```
Field mask = ChartPanel.class.getDeclaredField("panMask");
mask.setAccessible(true);
mask.set(yourChartPanel, Integer.valueOf(0)); // The "0" mask is equivalent to no mask. You could also set a different modifier.
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution still not provided with new version so i put what works flawlessly for me, it also auto zoom range axis when you scroll:

```
    ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    panel.setMouseZoomable(false);
    panel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
    panel.setDomainZoomable(true);
    panel.setRangeZoomable(false);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1680, 1100));
    panel.setZoomTriggerDistance(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    panel.setFillZoomRectangle(false);
    panel.setZoomOutlinePaint(new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f));
    panel.setZoomAroundAnchor(true);
    try {
        Field mask = ChartPanel.class.getDeclaredField("panMask");
        mask.setAccessible(true);
        mask.set(panel, 0);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    panel.addMouseWheelListener(arg0 -> panel.restoreAutoRangeBounds());
```

Now JFreeChart behaves like any other professional charting software.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

Regards
TA

```
 ChartPanel cp = new ChartPanel(chart)
  {
     /**
      * A hack to change the zoom and panning function.
      * With this override we can pan around by dragging.
      * If SHIFT is pressed we get the zoom rectangle.
      * @param e
      */
     @Override
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
     {
        int mods = e.getModifiers();

        int panMask = MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK;

        if (mods == MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK+MouseEvent.SHIFT_MASK)
        {
           panMask = 255; //The pan test will match nothing and the zoom rectangle will be activated.
        }

        try
        {
           Field mask = ChartPanel.class.getDeclaredField("panMask");
           mask.setAccessible(true);
           mask.set(this, panMask);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.mousePressed(e);
     }
  };
```

Comment: When answering on Stack Overflow, it's best to explain a bit about what your code does. As code only answers may not be understandable to the OP who asked the question